# How do I unlock Recon armor in Halo 3?

Tags: halo-3

How do I gain access to the "Recon" armor variant in Halo 3 multiplayer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It used to be that in Halo 3, the recon armor was not attainable except by working at Bungie or having a Bungie employee give it to you ([source](http://www.bungie.net/news/content.aspx?type=topnews&cid=12857)). Reasons for being gifted the armour included making an exceptionally interesting or funny level in Forge.

However, it is now possible to unlock the armour through normal means. You must have both Halo 3 and Halo:ODST, both of which much be associated with your bungie.net account. Then, you must complete all of the Vidmaster challenges, three of which are in Halo: ODST. ([Source/Tutorial](http://www.backyardgardener.com/halo3reconarmor.html))

Comment: Having completed these with the help of several other people, I will say that it is conceivably impossible to get the Recon armor without a dedicated group of 4 people (not necessarily the same 4 for each challenge).  Some challenges ostensibly require that you have 4 players, and since each challenge is fairly/extremely difficult, dragging around unmanned "guest" players with an extra controller is fairly infeasible (we tried it).  All that said - do it.  It is one of my most epic video game accomplishments ever.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you have to be bestowed the Recon armor by Bungie themselves. I don't think there's a way to unlock it. Usually they reward players with the Recon armor for good/useful/beneficial deeds in the community.

Comment: This used to be the case but is no longer the only way to get the armor.

Comment: Indeed it was.  The added 'unlockablility' of Recon armour was undoubtedly a good move on Bungie's part.  No one likes favouritism.